# HP Blade based georedundant configuration / IRF

Tags: hp, high-availability, blade-server

I'm planning to deploy 2 georedundant server farms. We chose HP Blade system. Every site would consist of:

- 1 x C3000 enclosure
- 4 x BL460c servers equiped additionally with 554M mezzanine (to have 4 LAN ports)
- 2 x 6125G blade switch

Incoming traffic (http, radius) will reach my servers via pair of loadbalancers (active-standby). The servers will run Linux.  I have 2 questions regarding network architecture and redundancy:

- how should I connect the blade switches, should I make 4 nodes' IRF ring over dedicated SFP ports? HP says that IRF could replace STP... Is that IRF good enough for interconnecting geographically separated sites? Do you recommend taht IRF over traditional techniques?
- is thare any advantage to have these mezzanine NIC providing those additional 2 ports per server blade, maybe 2 bonded interfaces and VLANs are enough to secure the link between server and switch blade?

Comment: Have you considered HP Virtual Connect interconnects, an external switch and skipping the mezzanine cards? It would simplify cabling.